# Indentation in Python not always necessary?

Tags: python, if-statement

I came across a piece of code (simplified for the question) structured like so:

```
while True:
    if x == y: break
```

My understanding of Python thus far is that the interpreter is highly dependent on tabs/spaces to understand the contents of things like loops and conditionals, but the above code style runs without issue, suggesting this isn't quite true.

Can someone explain the nuance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full details are explained in [Compound Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) in the reference docs. But as a brief summary:

Any "compound statement", like `if` can take *either* an **indented suite** of statements, or an inline **simple statement list**.*

So, what's the difference between these?

```
if x == y:
    break

if x == y: break
```

Really, nothing, except that the first is usually considered more readable and idiomatic. ([PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), the official style guide, says the second form is "generally discouraged", but "sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on the same line".)**

These have the exact same semantics, performance, etc. They'll even compile to the exact same bytecode. There is a small syntactic difference, but it only affects which error messages you get if you embed these in various illegal constructs.

---

So, can you put something more complicated than `break` there?

Yes. Notice that it's a simple statement ***list***. That means you can have multiple simple statements, separated by semicolons:

```
if x == y: print('Hey!'); x = -x; break
```

However, this is incredibly bad style. Unless you're trying to win a code-golf competition, don't do that.

But there are limits, too. Notice that it's a ***simple*** statement list. That means no compound statements. This is illegal:

```
if x == y: while True: print('loopy')
```

You can see the full list of simple statements [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html).

---

<sub>* An inline statement list is still considered a suite in the official grammar. But in loose discussion, suite more often means just the indented block alternative, not the inline alternative.</sub>

<sub>** In my experience, the most common place to see this in code by experienced devs is actually one of the places PEP 8 says to never do it: a class with a bunch of empty functions may have them on one line, like `def spam(self): pass`. That can make them hard to paste into the interactive interpreter, which is probably why PEP 8 says to never do it.</sub>

Comment: Fantastic breakdown of the differences. Thank you for that. The lack of assumptions of the reader's Python knowledge/skillset made this answer the winner.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation here is not required because your have [`simple_stmt`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html), `break`, in the [`if`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)'s [`suite`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-suite):

```
...
if_stmt      ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
                 ("elif" expression ":" suite)*
                 ["else" ":" suite]
...
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
...
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
...
```

In this case indentation is not required.

You can do this only with [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html),like  `return` or `break`, but you can't have a [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-compound_stmt), `if` like `while`, without indentation .

Comment: I was thinking showing the actual grammar would be a bad idea, but now that I see it posted here, I think even many novices will get it. Definite +1.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can always replace an intended block with a single line if the block consists only of a single statement.

E.g.

```
def f(x): return x

def f(x):
    return x
```

are equivalent. The same is true for any other block-expecting syntax in Python:

- if, else, elif, for, while, def, class, ...

Comment: That's not the right rule. There are plenty if single statements you can't put inline (like another single-line block statement), and you can easily put multiple statements on the line, like `if foo: print(x), print(y)`.

Comment: The reason why using a `,` works is because `print(x), print(y)` evaluates to a `tuple`. So in the case that you just described, `print(x), print(y)` is asking python to evaluate one statement which will return one `tuple`. This is often used in statements like `x, y = 5, 6`. In fact, you can place any constant in your code in a separate line, and program flow will *not* be affected. That is because every line is evaluated and if an `=` operator isnt present, the result is just discarded. This is the reason why some people often use multiple line strings rather than `#` for their comments.

Comment: @ssm: Sorry, that was a typo for `if foo: print(x); print(y)`, which is a statement list containing two simple statements.

Answer (score -1):

Thats the difference between a statemment and a compound statement. For example, in `C` you might do something like

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) printf("something");
```

or

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {printf("something");}
```

The `for` loop just executes a statement. However, when you include more than one statements within curly braces, like for example,

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {printf("something"); printf("something else");}
```

Then the entire thing within the curly braces is treated like one statement.

Its the same with Python ...

```
if x == y: 
    print 'abcd'   # These two statements are treated as 1 block
    break          # of statements
```

If you just had one statement, you wouldnt need to define a block.

Comment: This really is a false parallel. Especially because you can write `if x == y: print 'abcd'; break` and it works just fine.

Comment: Actually, using a semicolon to separate lines is still considered a compound statement in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: No it isn't. That's a `stmt_list`, which is not a kind of `compound_stmt`. In fact, if you look at it, `statement` on that page is defined as either a `stmt_list` or a `compound_stmt`, so they're clearly distinct things.